# using rethinkdb calculate distance between two latitude and longitude points

Tags: google-maps, geospatial, distance, rethinkdb

we are using rethinkdb geospatial features  to calculate distance between two latitude and longitude but the result returned by rethinkdb is different and looks wrong if i cross check on google maps or any distance calculator website. I have copied same code given rethinkdb help.

```
var point1 = r.point(-122.423246,37.779388);
var point2 = r.point(-117.220406,32.719464);
r.distance(point1, point2, {unit: 'km'})
// result returned 
734.1252496021841 km
```

but when i test same point on http://www.onlineconversion.com/map_greatcircle_distance.htm it return following result 642.1854781517294 km.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different from some other geo systems, RethinkDB uses the convention of having the longitude first, followed by the latitude.
We made that decision in order for being consistent with the GeoJSON format.

See http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/point/

From looking at your example, it looks like you've computed the distance correctly in RethinkDB, but entered the coordinates in the opposite direction in the online tool.

With latitude and longitude entered into the correct fields, I'm getting consistent results:
[image]

A more advanced note:
There is some difference behind the decimal point. The online calculator claims that "The script uses "Haversine" formula, which results in in approximations less than 1%." by which I assume it means up to 1% error, so this sort of deviation is to be expected.

RethinkDB uses geodesics on an ellipsoid for computing distances, based on the algorithm by C. F. F. Karney [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ7Ft.png). This is an extremely precise algorithm, that calculates geodesics up to the limits of double-precision floating point numbers.

You will see even more deviation from Google maps (it gives me 735.234653 km for these two points). It looks like Google maps uses great-circle distances, which do not take the ellipsoidal shape of the earth into account at all.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ7Ft.png) http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00190-012-0578-z

Comment: Thanks for detail. It solve my problem. I assumed that the rethinkDB used latitude and longitude position in similar to other geo systems.